# Biblatex Ibid. citations inside longtabu environment

Tags: biblatex, longtable, tabu

When using ibid citations inside a `longtabu` whilst on a page that already has a citation on it, the citation is ibid regardless of whether the author has been cited on that page already or not.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[style=authoryear-icomp]{biblatex}
\usepackage{longtable, tabu}
\usepackage{filecontents}
\begin{filecontents}{\jobname.bib}
@article{test1,
  author = {Doe, John},
  year = {1999},
  title = {Testing title},
  journaltitle = {Journal of tests},
  volume = {100},
  number = {5},
  pages = {100--200},
}
@article{test2,
  author = {Dee, Jane},
  year = {2000},
  title = {Second title},
  journaltitle = {Second journal},
  volume = {150},
  number = {10},
  pages = {300-400},
}
\end{filecontents}
\addbibresource{\jobname.bib}
\begin{document}
One \autocite{test1}.
\begin{longtabu}{X}
Two \autocite{test2}.
\end{longtabu}
\end{document}
```

This produces the following output:

[image: Output of a file with a citation inside longtabu with another citation elsewhere on the page]

Am I using `tabu` or `biblatex` incorrectly?

Comment: Sounds like a bug. I obtained the same (wrong) result.

Answer (score 3):

`tabu` uses some code derived partly from `tabularx` that sets the table multiple times to determine the column widths so you need to disable `\autocite` during the trials. `tabu` has a hook for that:

[image]

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[backend=bibtex,style=authoryear-icomp]{biblatex}
\usepackage{longtable, tabu}
\tabuDisableCommands{\def\autocite{}}
\usepackage{filecontents}
\begin{filecontents}{\jobname.bib}
@article{test1,
  author = {Doe, John},
  year = {1999},
  title = {Testing title},
  journaltitle = {Journal of tests},
  volume = {100},
  number = {5},
  pages = {100--200},
}
@article{test2,
  author = {Dee, Jane},
  year = {2000},
  title = {Second title},
  journaltitle = {Second journal},
  volume = {150},
  number = {10},
  pages = {300-400},
}
\end{filecontents}
\addbibresource{\jobname.bib}
\begin{document}

One \autocite{test1}.
\begin{longtabu}{X}
Two \autocite{test2}.
\end{longtabu}
\end{document}
```